# If I put my writing online/in contests, can I still get published?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, contests

I've entered writing into contests and put excerpts of my novels places like Tumblr.  If I wanted to seek publication for the pieces from which said excerpts are taken, could I still get published by a publisher (not self-publishing)?

Comment: I added the [self-publishing] tag because you're asking if a traditional publisher will accept your work if you've already self-published pieces of it.

Comment: I think some websites ask you to give them the rights to the poem you submit, so it probably depends on the platform you use. There's probably a Q&A section where they answer that question, or in doubt you can send an email, but I am pretty sure it varies from contest to contest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For excerpts, it should be fine as long as you're not publishing too much:

> **If I publish an excerpt online, does that mean the whole work or part of the work is considered previously published?**
>   Generally speaking, excerpts are okay to publish online, as long as they are on the short side (relative to the work in question).
>   <sub>[Writer's Relief](http://writersrelief.com/2013/11/19/what-is-considered-previously-published-writing/)</sub>

With contests, it's a little trickier. When you submitted your writing, what rights (if any) did you give away? (You read the fine print to make sure you still *have* the right to publish it, right?) In any case, most publishers [want the *exclusive* right to publish](https://morningstarlawgroup.com/frequently-asked-questions-publishing-agreements/).